# Broadleaf Commerce - My workflow activities are being executed twice

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

It seems that the built in workflow activities are being executed twice. I am testing the checkout workflow and the DecrementInventoryActivity is removing the quantity from the sku twice.

Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

I created the workflow like so:

```
<!-- Checkout Workflow Configuration -->
<bean id="blCheckoutWorkflow" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor">
   <property name="processContextFactory">
      <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.workflow.CheckoutProcessContextFactory"/>
   </property>
   <property name="activities">
      <list>
         <bean p:order="6000" id="blDecrementInventoryActivity" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.workflow.DecrementInventoryActivity">
            <property name="rollbackHandler" ref="blDecrementInventoryRollbackHandler" />
         </bean>
         <bean p:order="7000" id="blCompleteOrderActivity" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.checkout.service.workflow.CompleteOrderActivity">
            <property name="rollbackHandler" ref="blCompleteOrderRollbackHandler" />
         </bean>
         <bean p:order="9999999" class="com.mycompany.workflow.checkout.NotifyExternalInventorySystem" />
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="defaultErrorHandler">
      <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.DefaultErrorHandler">
         <property name="unloggedExceptionClasses">
            <list>
               <value>org.broadleafcommerce.core.inventory.service.InventoryUnavailableException</value>
            </list>
         </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Broadleaf 4.0, the DecrementInventoryActivity was added by default to the blCheckoutWorkflow. See the 3.1.10-4.0.0 migration notes at http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/4.0/migration-notes/3.1-to-4.0-migration/3.1.10-to-4.0-migration, in the section "Inventory Management".

This also goes for the `defaultErrorHandler`, and you can remove the `blCompleteOrderActivity` (that has always been managed in the framework). Basically, your customized blCheckoutWorkflow bean should change to:

```
<bean id="blCheckoutWorkflow" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor">
   <property name="activities">
      <list>
         <bean p:order="9999999" class="com.mycompany.workflow.checkout.NotifyExternalInventorySystem" />
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Starting with Broadleaf 3.0, any modifications to the blCheckoutWorkflow bean undergo the Broadleaf XML merging processing (which merges bean ids like `blCheckoutWorkflow`'s list of `activities`). In your case, since the `DecrementInventoryActivity` is already defined in the core framework XML file and your definition of `blCheckoutWorkflow` merges with it, the final result is 2 instances of the `DecrementInventoryActivity`.